# How do I fix other data not adding to previous data in react infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This my first time implementing react infinite scrolling. I ran into difficulty where the initial array of data keep repeating.

```
function Details() {
const [facility, setFacility] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const getFacility = useCallback(async () => {
    let skip = 0;
    setLoading(true)
    await Axios.get(
      `...apiUrl/${wardTitle}/ward/details?limit=${10}&skip=${skip}`
    ).then((response) => {
      const details = response.data.data;
      setFacility((prev) => [...prev, ...details]);
      setLoading(false)
    });
   

  }, [wardTitle]);

  const handleScroll =  (e) => {
    const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight} = e.currentTarget;
  
    if(clientHeight + scrollTop + 1 >= scrollHeight ){
      getFacility();
    }
  };


  
  useEffect(() => {
    getFacility();

  }, [getFacility]);

return (
<>
  {facility.map((cur) => (
  <div>{curr}</div>
 {loading && <h4>Loading ...</h4>
)
</>
)

}
```

Everything seems fine other than the data repetition. I dont know where i got it wrong in the call. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

i can see so many errors in your code check the spellings too.
You are not explaining what you really want to do?
infinite scrolling like facebook?